# Transforming code into looping instead of hardcode

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

```
policies_coeff = (test_policies_rl
            .join(rates_table,(
                  (test_policies_rl.version==rates_table.version) &
                  (test_policies_rl.sub_class==rates_table.cover) &
                  (test_policies_rl.rf_1==rates_table.RF) &
                  (test_policies_rl.rl_1==rates_table.rating_factor_1)
            ),"left")
            .withColumnRenamed("rating_factor_amount","rating_factor_amount_1")
            .withColumnRenamed("rating_factor_coefficient","rating_factor_coefficient_1")
            .withColumnRenamed("rating_factor_level", "rating_factor_level_1")
            .withColumnRenamed("rating_factor_rate", "rating_factor_rate_1")
            .drop(rates_table.version, rates_table.cover, rates_table.RF, rates_table.rating_factor_1, rates_table.rating_factor_2)
)
```

I want to write this code as a loop where , everywhere you see there is a 1 in this code, it could be 2,3,4,5,6,7... etc depending on the number columns in the table.

Tried using F strings

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the below approach in SparkSql as an example

```
test_policies_rl_data = [
    (1, 'A', 0.5, 0.8),
    (2, 'B', 0.6, 0.9),
    (3, 'C', 0.7, 1.0)
]
rates_table_data = [
    (1, 'A', 0.5, 0.8, 1.1, 10, 0.5, 1, 100),
    (2, 'B', 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 20, 0.6, 2, 200),
    (3, 'C', 0.7, 1.0, 1.3, 30, 0.7, 3, 300)
]
test_policies_rl = spark.createDataFrame(test_policies_rl_data, ['version', 'sub_class', 'rf_1', 'rl_1'])
rates_table = spark.createDataFrame(rates_table_data, ['version', 'cover', 'RF', 'rating_factor_1', 'rating_factor_2',
                                                       'rating_factor_amount', 'rating_factor_coefficient', 'rating_factor_level', 'rating_factor_rate'])
test_policies_rl.createOrReplaceTempView("test_policies_rl")
rates_table.createOrReplaceTempView("rates_table")
num_columns = 5
base_query = """
SELECT 
    t.*,
    r.rating_factor_amount AS rating_factor_amount_{},
    r.rating_factor_coefficient AS rating_factor_coefficient_{},
    r.rating_factor_level AS rating_factor_level_{},
    r.rating_factor_rate AS rating_factor_rate_{}
FROM test_policies_rl t
LEFT JOIN rates_table r
ON t.version = r.version
AND t.sub_class = r.cover
AND t.rf_1 = r.RF
AND t.rl_1 = r.rating_factor_1
"""
for i in range(1, num_columns + 1):
    query = base_query.format(i, i, i, i)
    policies_coeff = spark.sql(query)
    policies_coeff.show()
```

[image]

[image]

In the above code I have created temporary views test_policies_rl and rates_table using the `createOrReplaceTempView` method.
The variable num_columns is initialized, representing the total number of columns for the subsequent SQL query generation.
SQL query template base_query is defined, which performs a left join on test_policies_rl and rates_table based on specified conditions.
Creating a loop to generate and execute the SQL query for different numbers
A for loop is used to dynamically generate and execute SQL queries using the base_query. The loop iterates from 1 to num_columns.
Within the loop, the base_query is formatted using the loop variable i to specify the relevant column numbers in the SQL query.
The formatted query is executed using spark.sql(query), and the resulting DataFrame is displayed using the show() method.